# Declare a list of custom class as argument of function in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to type the inputs of a class method in Python 3. I want the argument to be a `list` of a custom class I created.
The definition of the method is as follows:

```
def add_report_data(self, report_data: list[ReportData]):
    pass
```

`ReportData` is a regular class defined as follows:

```
class ReportData:
    def __init__(self, system: str, value: int):
        self.__system = system
        self.__value = value
```

When executing my code I receive the following error:

```
    def add_report_data(self, report_data: list[ReportData]):
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

However, changing the type of `report_data` to simply `list` is able to execute, but this is not exactly what I want to do. Any idea on what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: `add_report_data` is part of `ReportData` class?

Comment: As the first comment implies, your question is not clear since you do not show a single, run-able code snippet that shows your error. Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to import [typing.List](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) and do `List[ReportData]`

`List[ReportData]` refers to the  generic version of `list` used for typing instead of `list[ReportData]`, which refers to the data type [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)

```
#Importing List from typing
from typing import List

class ReportData:
    def __init__(self, system: str, value: int):
        self.__system = system
        self.__value = value

class A:
    #Using List[ReportData]
    def add_report_data(self, report_data: List[ReportData]):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

As Devesh answered, your issue is that in effect you aren't typing the `report_data` parameter with a `list` of type `ReportData` rather you are trying to get the element from `list` at index `ReportData`, and that is giving you the error as `ReportData` is not a valid index.

When trying to type as a `list` of type `MyClass` you should use the `typing.List` and pass that the element types.

Answer (score 0):

On [Python 3.9+](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collections) and Python 3.7+ if you do this

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

you can use `list` as a type annotation. Your code should work as you've written it.